# Remove plus (+) sign from url & add minus (-) sign in Yii

Tags: php, yii

I have create a application using Yii Framework, I got a problem like below:

```
http://example.com/articles-89/Perk+and+UPR+stress+measurement/
```

I need to change like:

```
http://example.com/articles-89/perk-and-upr-stress-measurement/
```

add `-` this sign and upper case to lower case.

I'm using Yii & my config file is

main.php

```
'urlManager'=>array(
        'urlFormat'=>'path',
        'rules'=>array(
            'articles-<id:\d+>/<title:.*?>' => array('articles/view', 'urlSuffix' => '/', 'caseSensitive' => false),
            '/<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
            '/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            '/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        ),
    ),
```

I'm really appreciated if help anyone.

Answer (score 0):

You should modify pattern for `title` like following (allows lowercase chars and `-` sign):

`[a-z\-]+` instead of `.*?`

and prepare function that will be used to convert part of your url to lowercase and - sign, for example:

```
function convert($string)
{
    $replaceFrom = array('+');
    $replaceTo = array('-');

    $string = strtolower($string);

    return str_replace($replaceFrom, $replaceTo, $string);
}
```

And using this function you should prepare `title` parameter where you are generating urls, for example in creating hyperlink, etc.

Comment: How to use that please